# HTML <inline> can contain another <inline> element?

Tags: html, w3c, w3c-validation

Sounds like that is possible, per W3C am able to validate the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <title>Inline can another inline?</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
      <span>some text <span>comes here</span>.</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is that means an inline can contain another inline? Am confused, so long I thought only block-level elements can contain another block-level or inline elements. Also thought inline elements can contain only text. Can any one give some theory here with W3C reference or some reference, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct. It's described in HTML spec chapter 7 [The global structure of an HTML document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html):

> ### [7.5.3 Block-level and inline elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3)
>
> **Content model** - Generally, block-level elements may contain inline elements and other block-level elements. *Generally, inline elements may contain only data **and other inline elements***. Inherent in this structural distinction is the idea that block elements create "larger" structures than inline elements.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, some inline elements are allowed to contain inline elements. Here’s the definition of the [parameter entity *inline*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#inline):

> ```
> <!ENTITY % inline "#PCDATA | %fontstyle; | %phrase; | %special; | %formctrl;">
> ```

The content model for the elements described by the parameter entities [*fontstyle*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#fontstyle) and [*phrase*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#phrase) are then defined as follows:

> ```
> <!ELEMENT (%fontstyle;|%phrase;) - - (%inline;)*>
> ```

That means all elements described by *fontstyle* and *phrase* can contain *inline* elements.

The other *inline* elements that are described by [*special*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#special) and [*formctrl*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#formctrl) except the empty elements `BR`, `IMG`, `INPUT`, and except the elements `SCRIPT`, `SELECT`, and `TEXTAREA` (i.e. `A`, `OBJECT`, `MAP`, `Q`, `SUB`, `SUP`, `SPAN`, `BDO`, `LABEL`, and `BUTTON`) may contain inline elements (with some additional restrictions for `LABEL`, and `BUTTON`).